# vue.js render ajax data that contains vue.js syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-framework

**Vue.js version is: 2.x**

Hi. I'm sending an ajax request in vue js to another page and getting it's source which contains vue.js syntax such as events. When this source is added to property and property added to a template, the ajax data source (that contains vue.js syntax) can not be rendered and does not work properly.
For example template is:

```
<div id="app">
    {{{ foo }}}
</div>
```

and app.js is:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$http.get('/media').then(function(response){
            data = response.body;
            Vue.set(app, 'foo', data);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        alertVideoLink: function(event){
            alert(event.target.href);
        }
    }
});
```

In the above app.js code, ajax request returns this code (that is response.body):

```
<a href="/media/videos" @click.pevent.self="alertVideoLink(event)">Video Link</a>
```

but this link can't be rendered and does not work properly! I'm testing the render method and some useful hints, but no way found. Please help... Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me: is there why you have to return a template from your API endpoint, instead of a JSON which you then load into a custom component?

Comment: please suppose this way is only way! the data that returned from the ajax request contains vue syntax. but i'm not found any way to render this data. this is very useful way in some cases and very important to solved. thank you

Comment: If this is the only way, then you probably need to rewrite your consumable endpoint. It doesn’t make sense to pass template strings when you can simply pass data and interweave that content into components. If you come to SO with the “just write the code as I told you so” mentality, you’re in a wrong forum.

Comment: yes, i understand that the api endpoint should be json, but in my project this is the only way. thank you for your comment

Comment: anyone can't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an [Async Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components).

Something like...

```
components: {
  'async-media': () => Vue.http.get('/media').then(res => ({
    template: res.body,
    methods: {
      alertVideoLink (event) {
        this.$emit('click', event)
      }
    }
  }))
}
```

Then in your template...

```
<async-media @click="handleClickEventFromChildComponent" />
```

Here's an example using a timeout to fake *"load"* a template

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  components: {
    'async-media': () => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          template: '<a href="/media/videos" @click.prevent.self="alertVideoLink($event)">Video Link</a>',
          methods: {
            alertVideoLink(event) {
              this.$emit('click', event.target.href)
            }
          }          
        })
      }, 2000)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickEventFromChildComponent (href) {
      console.info('Clicked on', href)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>Wait 2 seconds</p>
  <async-media @click="handleClickEventFromChildComponent" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Are there any ways that '/media' to be dynamic?

Comment: @sgh370 that entirely depends on where it comes from in the first place. In your question, it's hard-coded

Comment: why your script not worked? no errors but not worked

Comment: @sgh370 did you implement the `handleClickEventFromChildComponent` method in your `Vue` instance?

Comment: yes, i want to manipulate the data that returned from ajax. any idea for this? for example replace some string from response

Comment: @sgh370 I've added an example code-snippet. Note that the template should use `alertVideoLink($event)` (note the dollar-sign prefix)

Answer (score 0):

@Phil's answer is correct but in my project need to be changed. in this case, the better way is: **using global components vs local components** because is simple for this work.